# How to make filters in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

How can I make some filters in Spring MVC? In URL I have for example

```
/example?parameter1=test&parameter2=apple;fruit&parameter3=Peter%20Park
```

How I can obtain all that parameters if I don't know how many are or where they are? Currently I have 3 function with 3 cases, if I have 0 parameters, or 1 or 2. But that are a bad idea because I can't create function for all possibilities can be exists.
So have anyone any suggestion for that? How can I make one function witch I can detected all that parameters and type of them?

Comment: You could create a function with all `@RequestParam`s marked as `optional=true` and analyse them inside the controller. Another approach would be to take in the `HttpServletRequest` directly and call [getParametersMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) or [getParameterNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames())

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the query string parameters as a Map in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping( "example" )
public String example( @RequestParam Map<String,String> queryParams) {
   //Iterate through map keys etc
}
```